# Reintroduce searching for tags in chat

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, chat-search

We always had the ability to [search for tags in chat-search](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=tag%3Acv-pls&room=11) using the syntax `tag:tag-name`, but after the changes in chat search a while back this is no longer possible.

I'm not sure when the changes were rolled out or with what goal (because in my experience it only made searching *anything* in chat even harder if not impossible), but it also had the side-effect of [breaking](https://github.com/Room-11/CVBacklogUI/issues/25) our chat crawler for the [cv-pls](/questions/tagged/cv-pls) tags [backlog](http://php.cv-pls.com/backlog).

Even without our backlog it is useful to search for tags in chat when as a user searching for messages.

Could you people please "fix" this and allow us to search for tags in chatsearch again?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this was never been a designed feature; it *looks* like you got this merely as a consequence of how the search index was treating the text. It is noted that you'd quite like this "back", but we will need to think about what the right thing to do is here, i.e. what does it *mean* to index chat by tags...

Comment: @MarcGravell What was done in the recent update that caused this issue? Can't you just revert that change if possible?

Comment: @cryptic 1) we moved from SQL FTS to elastic, and 2) no

Comment: +1 not because I ever use it but because it makes sense

Comment: @MarcGravell is there a decision if this is possible and if it will be fixed? I'd like to know if I need to drop chat support for our backlog and move forward without it. Thanks. =o)

Answer (score 3):

You can search for tags in chat by searching for `tagged/tag-name`. While this is not nearly as intuitive as being able to search for `tag:tag-name`, it at least permits you to be able to find the messages you're interested in (i.e. that contain a specific tag).

For the specific search you were interested in, finding all messages with [cv-pls](/questions/tagged/cv-pls) in the [PHP room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php), you could use [a search for `tagged/cv-pls`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=tagged%2Fcv-pls&user=&room=11).

I assume this works because you are searching the chat message for the URL that's generated for the tag. In the case of the above [cv-pls](/questions/tagged/cv-pls) tag, it's searching for `tagged/cv-pls` in `//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls`, which is in the `href` used for the tag HTML. The change from being able to search for `tag:tag-name` to now being able to search for the URL may be accounted for due to changing the search indexing from scanning the chat message Markdown to scanning the HTML generated for the message from the Markdown.